# How to delete value from mupltiple array using key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need one help. I need to remove value from multiple array by matching the key using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
$str="ram,,madhu,kangali";
$strid="1,2,,3";
$arr=explode(",",$str);
$arrId=explode(",", $strid);
```

I have two array `i.e-$arr,$arrId` which has some blank value. Here I need if any of array value is blank that value will delete and the same index value from the other array is also delete.`e.g-suppose for $arr the 1 index value is blank and it should delete and also the the first index value i.e-2 will also delete from second array and vice-versa.`please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 $str="ram,,madhu,kangali";
$strid="1,2,,3";
$arr=explode(",",$str);
$arrId=explode(",", $strid);
$arr_new=array();
$arrId_new=array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  if(($value != "" && $arrId[$key] != "")){
    array_push($arr_new, $value);
    array_push($arrId_new, $arrId[$key]);
  }
}

var_dump($arr_new);
var_dump($arrId_new);
```

Comment: its giving the output like `{"0":"ram","3":"kangali"}` . where its coming in different format.

Comment: i need like this ["ram","kangali"].

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if ( empty($value) || empty($arrId[$key]) ) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
        unset($arrId[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can zip both lists together and then only keep entries where both strings are not empty:

```
$zipped = array_map(null, $arr, $arrId);
$filtered = array_filter($zipped, function ($tuple) {
    return !empty($tuple[0]) && !empty($tuple[1]);
});
$arr = array_map(function($tuple) {return $tuple[0];}, $filtered);
$arrId = array_map(function($tuple) {return $tuple[1];}, $filtered);
```

[Link to Fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d4df56b8616a23c6252801a02970d5126c3af660)

Comment: Its format is different like `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "ram"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "kangali"
}` coming.

Comment: Just do `$arr = array_values($arr)` to rearrange the keys